# How can i make my new periodictask working Django 1.6 /Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery

I had a Django project to maintain,
I would add new periodic task :
 **tasks.py**

class ArchiveJobsTask(PeriodicTask):

```
    run_every = crontab()

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        logger.info('Arching jobs')
        qs         = Job.objects.filter(status='W', expiration_date__lt= datetime.datetime.today().date()).update(status='A')
        return 'Jobs archived.'
```

I configured the celery setting:

```
[program:celery]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/var/www/keejob_env/bin/celery worker -A keejob --loglevel=INFO -Q jobs,experiences
directory=/var/www/keejob_env/keejob
user=www-data
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 166600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

my setting file : setting.py :

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'mailing.tasks.SendJobAlerts': {'queue': 'alerts'},
    'mailing.tasks.SendApplicationEmail': {'queue': 'applications'},
    'job_applications.tasks.ApplicationNotifyResponsibleTask': {'queue': 'applications'},
    'recruiter.jobs.tasks.SendDailyApplicationsTask': {'queue': 'jobs'},
    'recruiter.jobs.tasks.SendDailyExpirationTask': {'queue': 'jobs'},
    'recruiter.jobs.tasks.RefreshJobsTask': {'queue': 'jobs'},
    'recruiter.jobs.tasks.ArchiveJobsTask': {'queue': 'jobs'},
    'jobseeker.tasks.CronExperienceJobseekerTask': {'queue': 'experiences'},
}
```

I cannot make this task working, Help please !
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Django management commands,

Same way you run the runserver, shell and dbshell etc.

http://django-chinese-docs-16.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/custom-management-commands.html